# Rails 3 - Require - Path Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, require

I have:

Windows XP Professional SP3
Ruby 1.8.7
Rails 3.0.10
Bundler 1.0.15
ImageMagick 6.5.6 Q8
Rmagick 2.12.9

**My gemfile:**

```
gem 'rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32', '2.12.0', :path => 'c:/sites/uplodify/vendor'
```

**My controller:**

```
require 'RMagick'
```

**Here I have installed my rmagick gem:**

```
c:/ruby/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32/
```

But when I launch the controller, there is a message:

```
no such file to load -- RMagick
```

Then, I change `require 'RMagick'` to `require 'c:/ruby/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32/lib/RMagick.rb'`, and **it's working!!!**

**Question:**

why `require 'RMagick'` is not working, but `require 'c:/ruby/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32/lib/RMagick.rb'` is working????

Thanks a lot!

**ADDED:** Hi, people. I glad to say how I solved the problem. My way was following recomendations on http://www.waydotnet.com/blog/2010/02/rmagick-on-ruby-1-9-1-i386-mingw32-work-d/....step by step...

Comment: How did you install RMagick? It looks like `c:/ruby/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32/lib` isn't in your Ruby path.

Comment: This is weird, you have both `c:/sites/uplodify/vendor` and `c:/ruby/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32/lib/RMagick.rb` defined as paths for the gem.

Comment: I have installed rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32 in this way: gem install rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32. A see that in gem's repository there is rmagick (c:/ruby/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32/). And when I use require 'RMagick' from Ruby application - Ok! But from rails controller require 'RMagick' - not work!

Comment: I hoped that when i will include in Rails gemfile this line: gem 'rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32', '2.12.0', :path => 'c:/sites/uplodify/vendor' (in c:/sites/uplodify/vendor there is rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32.gem), require 'RMagick' in controller will work. But not!

Comment: also...there is no "rmagick" entries in $LOADED_FEATURES...

Answer (score 0):

In your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rmagick', '2.12.0', :require => 'RMagick'
```

and remove the `require` in your controller.

You're not really supposed to `require` your dependencies in your rails app, bundler should do it automatically. The `:require` option tells bundler that it should do a `require 'RMagick'` so you don't have to do it manually.

Comment: Thanks for answer, Binoet. But it does't work for me. When I added line gem 'rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32', '2.12.0', :require => 'RMagick' to my gemfile, then I make "bundle install". There is error "Could not find gem 'rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32 (= 2.12.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile."

Comment: Edited my answer, I'm quite tired today. This should work better.

Comment: No problem, Benoit )
But gem 'rmagick', '2.12.0', :require => 'RMagick' not working for me too. Error during bundle install: "Installing rmagick (2.12.0) with native extensions C:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site
_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:552:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)"
It's because for Windows OS there is pre-compiled gem named rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32.gem.

Comment: I think that using gem 'rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32', '2.12.0', :path => 'c:/sites/uplodify/vendor', :require => 'RMagick' is more correctly but also not working. Somehow in Ruby app there are no problems using rmagick ((

Comment: Could you try what I wrote, with the command `bundle install --system` to install the gems?

Comment: Yes of course. I tried. I have writed result: Installing rmagick (2.12.0) with native extensions C:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site
_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:552:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

        C:/Ruby/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

Can't install RMagick 2.12.0. Can't find MagickWand.h.

Comment: Can you try to launch `irb` in the windows console and run `require 'RMagick'`? I assume you already tested this (from your question) but it does not hurt to try.

Comment: Yes, I tested it, it's working...irb->require 'rubygems'->true-> require 'Rmagick'->true. From Ruby app it's working with no problem...

Comment: Can you try the same thing in your rails console?

Comment: I cannot run console because in gemfile there is line **gem 'rmagick', '2.12.0', :require => 'RMagick'** and console give me a error message **Could not find gem 'rmagick (= 2.12.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. Try running `bundle nstall** And ""bundle install** gives me a message that I posted earlier...

Comment: Yep, but remove the rmagick line in your Gemfile, run bundle install and then try it.

Comment: Sorry for disturb, Benoit. But when I removed the magick line from gemfile, and maked bundle install, then rails c->require 'rubygems'->nil->require 'RMagick'->nil. Can't understand why require returns nil but not true when I launch that in rbi

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry, but I have exhausted all my ideas. You really should find someone to help you face to face, it's usually much easier to fix this kind of problem when you're in front of the computer. Sorry and good luck.

Comment: Hey, Benoit.Thanks again for you help. I solved the problem following the recommendations http://www.waydotnet.com/blog/2010/02/rmagick-on-ruby-1-9-1-i386-mingw32-work-d/. I have compiled rmagick source ))

Comment: Glad you found your solution! It would be awesome if you could edit your question to tell people how you resolved this.